# Loop wregex always return false and high cpu usage around 50%

Tags: c++, regex, winapi

I have a bunch keyword need to loop to match a wchar_t string.

the string is

> 5698@#$%notepad^&343235/ chrome $56&6556firefox$%#$23

and the keyword is

> notepad, chrome, firefox

I try to loop it always return FALSE and when i see cpu usage. it so extensive around 50%.

this the code.

```
            unsigned int i;

            wchar_t * keyword[] = {L"chrome", L"notepad", L"firefox");

            for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                wchar_t * s = L"5698@#$%notepad^&343235/ chrome $56&6556firefox$%#$23";

                wcmatch m;

                wchar_t regex[MAX_PATH];

                swprintf(regex, MAX_PATH, L"%s%s", L".+", keyword[i]);

                wregex r(regex);

                if (regex_search(s, m, r))
                {
                    cout << "It's found" << endl;
                }

                else
                {
                    cout << "It's not found" << endl;
                }
```

thsi my real project code. enumerate process and match the process and return bool value.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <Psapi.h>
#include <string>
#include <regex>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    FILE *pFile;
    wchar_t *file = L"d:\\a.txt";
    wchar_t line[100][MAX_PATH];
    unsigned int a = 0;
    if (_wfopen_s(&pFile, file, L"r, ccs = UNICODE") == 0)
    {
        while (fgetws(line[a], 100, pFile))
        {
            a++;
        }
    }

    DWORD aProcesses[1024], cbNeeded, cProcesses;
    unsigned int i;

    if (!EnumProcesses(aProcesses, sizeof(aProcesses), &cbNeeded))
    {
        return 1;
    }

    cProcesses = cbNeeded / sizeof(DWORD);

    wchar_t jszProcessName[4096] = { 0 };

    for (i = 0; i < cProcesses; i++)
    {
        if (aProcesses[i] != 0)
        {
            wchar_t szProcessName[MAX_PATH] = TEXT("Unknown");
            DWORD processID = aProcesses[i];

            HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | 
                                        PROCESS_VM_READ,
                                        FALSE, processID);

            if (NULL != hProcess)
            {
                HMODULE hMod;
                DWORD cbNeeded;

                if (EnumProcessModules(hProcess, &hMod, sizeof(hMod),
                    &cbNeeded))
                {
                    GetModuleBaseName(hProcess, hMod, szProcessName,
                        sizeof(szProcessName) / sizeof(TCHAR));

                    wcsncat_s(jszProcessName,szProcessName , 1000);


                }
            }
        }
    }


    unsigned int c;

        for (c = 0; c < a; c++)
        {
            wchar_t * s = jszProcessName;

            wcmatch m;

            wchar_t regex[MAX_PATH];

            swprintf(regex, MAX_PATH, L"%s%s", L".+", line[c]);

            wregex r(regex);

            if (regex_search(s, m, r))
            {
                cout << "It's found" << endl;
            }

            else
            {
                cout << "It's not found" << endl;
            }

        }




    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f38755f4d6c4573a). Produces compilation warnings, but works.

Comment: [Also cannot reproduce using Visual C++](http://rextester.com/QFFV30081).  Exactly what compiler and compiler version are you using?  Also, please post a [mcve].  We have no idea if this is just part of a larger program, and the larger program itself has caused some sort of memory corruption.

Comment: @wally It''s weird. its work but when i try with my real project still return false.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie i post my real project with the answer wally i think its should return true

Comment: @SteveJobs `wchar_t line[100][MAX_PATH]; .. while (fgetws(line[a], 100, pFile))` -- If `a >= 100`, then this overwrites memory.  There is nothing in your code that stops the file read at 100 lines.  Second, no one can verify this works unless `a.txt` is known.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie in my a.txt only 5 keyword = 5 lines. `chrome\nnotepad\nfirefox\ndisplay\nkeyboard`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I know the problem now. the problem is from getline that return add `\n` in the end string. thats why not match. but now the problem is cpu usage. what's make it so high?

Comment: By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0), for SE to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. Please don't make more work for people by vandalizing your posts.

Answer (score 0):

have your regex keywords separated by `|` characters:

```
(notepad|chrome|firefox)
```

https://regex101.com/r/PAZBbx/1

Comment: You're wrong to understand the code. thats regex patern is combine from swfprintf with .* and keyword. so it will .*notepad each loop. so it will .*chrome and .*firefox.

Comment: when i try with no loop. it return as exactly but with loop it always return false.